# Get (text) in XPath

Tags: html, dom, xpath, html-parsing

I have the following DOM structure / HTML, I want to get (just practicing...) the marked data.
[image]

The one that is under the h2 element. that div[@class="coordsAgence"] element, has some more div children below and some more h2's.. so doing:

```
div[@class="coordsAgence"]
```

Will get that value, but with additional unneeded text.
**UPDATE**: The value (From this example) that I basically want is that: "GALLIER Dennis" text.

Comment: The picture really doesn't help a lot. A simplified text version would be a lot more useful when people build up answers.

Comment: Downvoted. Code as a screenshot, not nice at all.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

It seems you want the first text node in that div:

```
div[@class="coordsAgence"]/text()[1]
```

should do it.

Note that this assumes that there is actually no whitespace between those comments inside `<div class="coordsAgence">`; otherwise that whitespace will constitute additional text nodes that you'll have to account for.

Answer (score 1):

Get the first text node following the first `h2` in the `div` with class `"coordsAgence"`:

```
div[@class='coordsAgence']/h2[1]/following-sibling::text()[1]
```

Note that this first expression returns the first text node after the first `h2` even when some other node appears between the two. If you want to return the text only when it's the node that  *immediately* follows the first `h2`, then try something like this:

```
div[@class='coordsAgence']/h2[1][following-sibling::node()[1][self::text()]]/following-sibling::text()[1]
```

Answer (score 0):

using Python/Scrapy to get text from h1 tag(for example):

```
response.xpath(
        "//div[contains(@class, 'class_name')]//h1[contains(@class, 'class_name')]/text()"
    ).get()
```